# How to Create a Service Principal for Azure database for PostgreSql single server

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, service-principal, azure-postgresql, azure-service-principal

As per the documentation from Microsoft for [Data encryption for Azure Database for PostgreSQL Single server by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-data-encryption-portal) , the steps mentioned tell to create a service principal for Azure PostgreSql single server option, while adding an Access Policy in Azure key vault.

I wanted to know how can I create a service principal for Azure Postgresql. I googled across the web but didn't find any descriptive link or documentation to do this.

Can someone please help me achieve this?

Comment: Thanks @AnsumanBal-MT , let me try this sometime and will accept the answer if it resolves the issue..

Comment: Hello @VSS, just checking if the issue got resolved using the solution or if there is any other update?

Comment: Hi @AnsumanBal-MT I have yet to try the solution.. it will take some time and I will definitely accept the answer if it solves the issue.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please follow the below steps to fix the issue:**

1. You have to configure the data encryption first as shown below which will
   fail because you don't have a service principal for it but this step
   is necessary as it will create a new service principal for your
   PostgreSQL server.

   [image]
2. After the above step fails , go to your `Keyvault>>access policies>> add access policy.`

   You will be able to see the service principal created for the
   Postgre and it will have the same name as the PostgreSQL server and
   add the required permissions for the principal as shown below:

   [image]

   [image]
3. Go to the data encryption section for PostgreSQL server again and do
   the settings like below , it will be successfully saved:

   [image]